# Super Resolution in GIMP

Tags: resolution, gimp

Does anyone have any tips on how to apply Super Resolution techniques in GIMP? I have done a lot of reading but I could not find any examples for GIMP...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say, resynthesizer will not manage to obtain real detail, since it's adding fake points through interpolation, rather than obtaining more real detail. What the original question suggests is about stacking multiple real shots and obtain higer resolution, like this:
http://mentat.za.net/supreme/
https://aperture64.wordpress.com/2014/03/19/improving-image-quality-with-stacking-and-super-resolution/

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Answer (score 0):

You could try the resynthesizer plugin [available here](http://registry.gimp.org/node/25219). It can do a resize of the image, intelligently interpolating missing pixels using the resynthesizer algorithm. I haven't had much luck with it; but, I'm sure results will vary, depending on the type of image.